# githubへgit pushしようとすると403エラーとなる

Tags: git, github

```
remote: Permission to AAA/abc.git denied to BBB.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AAA/abc.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

`git add .` `git commit` した後に`git push`した結果上記のようなエラーがでてきました。
どこの設定を変更すれば解決しますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのリポジトリ(AAA/abc)にpushする権限を持たないユーザー(BBB)でログインしているようです。

HTTPSをお使いのようですから、push時に入力したユーザー名・パスワードがそのリポジトリで使っているものかどうか、確認してみてください。

---

リモートリポジトリにhttp(s)で接続していて認証が必要な場合には、基本的には毎回ログインを求められます。ただそれでは面倒なので、資格情報を記憶する credential helperという仕組みがあります。

これはURLごとに記憶するわけですが、デフォルトではパスを無視するため、前回 `https://github.com/` にログインした際のユーザー名・パスワードでログインしてしまったようです。

対策としては、`https://user@github.com/`としてURLにユーザー名を含めてしまうのが一番簡単だとは思いますが、一応他の方法も載せておきます。

- 全く記憶しないようにする： configから`credential.helper`を消す
- 記憶している情報を消す： `git credential reject` コマンドを使う
- 記憶する際にパスも考慮するようにする： `credential.useHttpPath`をtrueにする

credential helper によってはGit側から伝えられたpathやusernameを無視する可能性もあります。その場合はこれらの方法が役立つかもしれません。

参考

- [Git - 認証情報の保存](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%96%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E3%81%AE%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98)
- [How can I store keychain credentials for multiple Github accounts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24277934/2818869)

Comment: (BBB)でログインというのはGithubにログインしているアカウントのことですか？ローカルでの設定とは無関係ですか？

Comment: @denden 「Githubにログイン」「ローカルでの設定」が何を指しているのかわかりませんが、ブラウザとは別です。httpsアクセスをお使いのようですから、push時にログインを求められるはずで、その際に使ったアカウントです。

Comment: ログ‌​インを求められるはずですが、今回の件では求められないです、、、
いきなりエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: @denden 以前アカウントAAAでpushしたことがあるなら、そのログイン情報が記憶されている可能性はありますが・・・心当たりはありますか？

Comment: 以前のものが記憶されているかと思いますが、configに残るものでしょうか。どこの修正が必要になるものですか。

Comment: [http://blog.tokoyax.com/entry/git/git-push-403error]
上記サイトで解決いたしました。失礼しました。