# GitHub 上でコミットを別アカウントによるものとして表示させたい

Tags: git, github

社内勉強会の1つのリポジトリに複数のアカウントからコミットする様子をデモしたいのですがユーザーを変更する方法がわかりません。

ローカル側でフォルダAとフォルダBを作成、GitHub ユーザーも２つ用意しそれぞれのフォルダに割り当てて、「Aフォルダのローカルリポジトリを変更、Bフォルダのローカルリポジトリも変更、このようにプルリクしてやっていきます〜」みたいな見せ方をしたいのです。

しかし、GitHub に別ユーザーでサインインしても発行されるsshやhttpsは同一で、結果AもBも普段から使っているユーザーからのコミットとして表示されてしまいます。

どのように、すれば良いのでしょうか？
関連: [同じPCから複数のGitのアカウントを切り替える方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/29463/3054)

Comment: pushしたコミットの作者が意図したGItHubユーザにならないということですか?GitHubユーザをそれぞれのフォルダに割り当てたとは、具体的に何をしたのですか?

Comment: 具体的には何もしてません。それぞれのフォルダに割り当ててデモがしたい。しかしどのようにそれぞれに割りてるかはわからない。もしくは、Aコミット→Aログアウト→Bログイン→Bコミットのような流れができない。という状態です。

Comment: 「[同じPCから複数のGitのアカウントを切り替える方法](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29463/%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98pc%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e8%a4%87%e6%95%b0%e3%81%aegit%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a2%e3%82%ab%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e5%88%87%e3%82%8a%e6%9b%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)」の重複としてマークされましたが、リンクの質問はクレデンシャルの不一致でpushできないという問題で、この質問はpushしたコミットが意図したGitHubユーザにならないという問題なので、異なるものだと思います。

Comment: 「意図したGi‌​tHubユーザにならない」のは質問者さんがコメントされていますが、方法が解らず何も行なっていないからです（つまり願っているだけ）。ですから、原因は明らかで、そこに解説は必要ないと思いました。「同じPCから複数のGitのアカウントを切り替える方法」が解れば自ずとこの質問者さんの問題も解決するはずです。

Comment: @kaitoy  とは言え、やろうとしている事が異なる（それぞれのアカウントでの操作対象のリポジトリが、同じか、違うか）のは確かですので、以前の質問には当て嵌まらない別の回答がありえるという事でしたら、再オープンに投票しようと思います。何かありそうでしょうか。

Comment: コミットの作者とGitHubユーザは、コミットに記録されたメールアドレスで紐付けられているようなので、リポジトリの設定でメールアドレスを変えてコミットしてpushすれば質問者の望むことができるかと思っています。逆に、「同じPCから複数のGitのアカウントを切り替える方法」の回答を実施してもだめな気がします。(回答の最後にちらっと書いてある`.git/config`の設定が要ると思っています。)

Comment: @kaitoy なる程、デモの為には必須ですね。むしろ、ログに残る名前だけでも設定すればよくて、そこに認証は関係ないので何なら Rob Pike からのコミットを作る事も出来るという事ですね。

Comment: 1台のPCでデモしたいだけなら、VMWareなりで別OSをインストールしてやったらどうですか？

Answer (score 5):

GitHubでは**コミットに使うメールアドレス**で「コミットを作成したユーザー」を識別しています。初めてGitを使う際に何らかのツールや以下のコマンドを通して設定したやつです。

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

例えば上の場合、GitHubは `your_email@example.com` が登録されているユーザーによるコミットとして表示します。

参考 [Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/) - GitHubのヘルプ記事

なので別のGitHubユーザーとして表示させたい場合は、コミットに使うメールアドレスを変更します。なおGitHub以外のツールやgitコマンドではコミットに使う名前が表示されることになるので、以下の例では名前も併せて変更しています。

### 方法1. リポジトリごとに設定する

```
# GitHub以外ではこの名前が表示されるので、併せて変更するとよい
git config user.name "Your Another Name"
git config user.email "your_another_email@example.com"
```

`--global` オプションを付けずに実行することで、リポジトリの `.git/config` に設定を書き込むことができます。こうすればそのリポジトリでだけ特定のメールアドレスを使うことができます。もしくは `.git/config` をテキストエディタで開いて、次の設定を追加しても構いません。

```
[user]
    name = Your Another Name
    email = your_another_email@example.com
```

一度このように設定しておけば、再起動しても残りますし、別のツールでコミットする際にも適用されます。ただしローカルリポジトリに保存される設定ですから、cloneしなおした場合は再設定する必要があります。

### 方法2. 環境変数で一時的に変更する

環境変数 `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` および `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` で一時的に変更することもできます。いつもではないが時々別名義を使いたいという場合には、これらを設定するコマンドやスクリプトを用意しておくと便利かもしれません。

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Your Another Name"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="your_another_email@example.com"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Your Another Name"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="your_another_email@example.com"
```

※ author と committer は両方設定します。

---

> GitHub に別ユーザーでサインインしても発行されるsshやhttpsは同一

GitHubの場合

- SSHではユーザー名固定、どの鍵で接続するかで識別する
- HTTPSではBasic認証でユーザー名・パスワードを指定するが、発行されるURLには含まれていない

ので、現時点ではユーザーに依らず同じURLが発行されます。

ですがこれは実際のところ、**当該リポジトリへのアクセス権を持つかどうか**の判定にしか使われません。でなければ同じSSH鍵を複数のユーザーに設定したときに困ってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

[@unarist さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/33409/754)の、

> 方法2. 環境変数で一時的に変更する

に対して追加で、 [direnv](https://direnv.net/) を用いると、ディレクトリごとに環境変数の使い分け、が実現できます。

さらに、 direnv には `source_up` という機能があり、これを用いるとディレクトリ階層を登って `.envrc` を追加で読み込ませることができます。

自分が良くやるのは、組織毎にディレクトリを作成し(大体は、 github の(組織)アカウント名を使っています)、 git のリポジトリをそれぞれの組織ディレクトリの中に作成し、組織ディレクトリ自体に `.envrc` を配置しそこで `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` と `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` を設定、各リポジトリ毎に追加の環境変数があれば、 `source_up` しながらリポジトリ毎に `.envrc` を作成、といった形で運用しています。